# Overlaying an image only on currently clicked Div - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to overlay a small checkmark (an image) over whatever image/div is currently clicked. I would prefer to use just javascript if possible, since the rest of my program is written in that.

```
$('#checked').click(function(){
  if ( $('.selected').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
     $('.selected').css('visibility','visible').siblings('visibility','hidden');
  else
     $('.selected').css('visibility','hidden');
});

<div id="checked">
   <div id="axisFrame">
      <img name="msImg" id='axisSofa' src="img.jpg" />
   </div>

<div id="checked">
    <div id="fionaFrame">
       <img name="msImg" id='fionaSofa' src="img.jpg" />
    </div>

.selected {
   width: 46px;
   height: 46px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -23px auto 0 -23px;
   background-image: url(images/msSelected.png);
   z-index: 10;
   visibility:"hidden";
}
```

I want the **msSelected** image to overlay on the div that is most recently clicked and then disappear when another element is clicked (basically a selector).

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I don't see any element on your code with class `selected` ... Aside you can't use the same ID name for both elements ID must be unique and taht will break your JS instead use a classname

Comment: You definitely don't have to use another language for that - javascript ( or here jquery ) will do the job.
Please posted a live code example so we can help you with a working example.

Comment: DaniP, he named the image by filename ( msSelected.png ) not class, that's why ...

Comment: @Romainpetit OP's code is `$('.selected')` so searching for an element with that class and also is there the CSS declaration for that class but on the HTML there is no element with that class assigned, or some JS creating the element. Then it's a bit unclear where is the code going

Comment: Oh, true @DaniP
Are our comments helping AGray ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this - right now nothing sets selected items as selected, and visibility:hidden will hide the whole div tag, including the background image.

One solution would be to have the div background always a checkbox and hide the img tag when clicked:

```
$('#msImg').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
     $(this).css('visibility','visible');
  else
     $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
});

<div class="checked">
   <div id="axisFrame">
      <img name="msImg" id='axisSofa' src="img.jpg" />
   </div>

<div class="checked">
    <div id="fionaFrame">
       <img name="msImg" id='fionaSofa' src="img.jpg" />
    </div>

.checked {
   width: 46px;
   height: 46px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -23px auto 0 -23px;
   background-image: url(images/msSelected.png);
   z-index: 10;
}
```